# How to install Hercules Webcam Deluxe

Tags: webcam, makefile, make

I am trying to install a Hercules Webcam Deluxe on my Ubuntu 11.10 (64 bits). I followed this guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ov51x

Step by step, only changing

wget http://www.rastageeks.org/downloads/ov51x-jpeg/ov51x-jpeg-1.5.4.tar.gz

by 1.5.9, because that is the latest version.

I get stacked here:

```
2.4. Prepare the installation files

make

2.5. Compile

Compile the modules:

sudo make install
```

Because, when I enter that in a terminal, I get this error:

```
make: *** No hay objetivos.  Alto.
```

For you, non Spanish-speaking-people, that is roughly translated as: "There are no objectives. Stop"

So... what can I do?

Thanks

Edit:

Terminal output:

```
    Configurando build-essential (11.5ubuntu1) ...
mrpotato@mrsobremesa:~$ wget http://www.rastageeks.org/downloads/ov51x-jpeg/ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9.tar.gz
--2011-12-08 03:33:47--  http://www.rastageeks.org/downloads/ov51x-jpeg/ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9.tar.gz
Resolviendo www.rastageeks.org... 213.251.174.188
Conectando a www.rastageeks.org|213.251.174.188|:80... conectado.
Petición HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 200 OK
Longitud: 88197 (86K) [application/x-gzip]
Guardando en: «ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9.tar.gz.1»

100%[======================================>] 88.197       245K/s   en 0,4s    

2011-12-08 03:33:47 (245 KB/s) - «ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9.tar.gz.1» guardado [88197/88197]

mrpotato@mrsobremesa:~$ tar -xvf ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9.tar.gz
ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9/
ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9/test/
ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9/test/Makefile
ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9/test/getjpeg.c
ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9/Makefile
ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9/ov51x-jpeg-core.c
ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9/ov518-decomp.c
ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9/ov51x-jpeg.h
ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9/ov519-decomp.c
ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9/ov511-decomp.c
ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9/ov7670.h
ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9/ChangeLog
mrpotato@mrsobremesa:~$ cd ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9
mrpotato@mrsobremesa:~/ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9$ make
make: *** No hay objetivos.  Alto.
mrpotato@mrsobremesa:~/ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9$ sudo make
make: *** No hay objetivos.  Alto.
mrpotato@mrsobremesa:~/ov51x-jpeg-1.5.9$
```

Comment: Most of the time make errors are due to missing dependencies. Can you please post or pastebin the 5-10 lines above that error message? Also, check the README for dependencies.

Comment: There is no readme file in the download, nor in the rastageeks website, which is full of spam. I didn't get any error :S
Anyway, I copied what my terminal shows.

Comment: FYI - You should probably run make as a user, without sudo. You only need sudo for `make install`. Did you install `build-essential` ?

Comment: I did, it's in the first line of the output:
"Configurando build-essential (11.5ubuntu1) ..."

The "sudo" thing is just that I tried it with and without, just in case it was because of that.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: I am. I haven't tried antything new,I gave up. 

A friend of mine promised to help me, though, so I'll update this if I get a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the Makefile, you can find the source is for 2.6 kernel.  After manually modifying the 2.6 to 3.0, you will be able to compile, but more missing files you will expect.