# WebCam is not recognized on my Samsung 300v5a-s19

Tags: drivers, 12.10, webcam, samsung

I have Samsung 300v5a-s19ru laptop, and its WebCam is not recognized. I tried to follow [this manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam), but it doesn't work for me.

1. When I'm trying to start Cheese, it doesn't see any WebCam at all. Its Output:

   ```
   ** (cheese:8161): WARNING **: cheese-main.vala:251: Error: No device found

      (cheese:8161): cheese-CRITICAL **: cheese_camera_device_get_device_node: assertion CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

      (cheese:8161): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_new_string: assertion string != NULL' failed

      (cheese:8161): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion value != NULL' failed

      (cheese:8161): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion value != NULL' failed

      (cheese:8161): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

   ** (cheese:8161): CRITICAL **: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion device != NULL' failed
   ```
2. I tried install **`Ov51x`**, but as I can understand it doesn't work on linux kernel > 3.0. Trying to follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ov51x), item 2.4 fails:

   `% make`

   `make: *** No targets.  Stop.`

   In [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/109893/99179) answer on askubuntu it's written, that Ov51x works on < 2.6 kernels only
3. In Samsung Tech Support they said that drivers for Linux does not exist, but they said also, that in my laptop WebCam **Sunplus Tech SCB-1100N** is used.

What do I do to make it work? What driver or module should I use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was so simple and close

The issue was that the webcam is switched off at boot time with the `Samsung Tools`.

I accidentally discovered that in the settings of the `Samsung Tools` webcam toggle is set to "*Last Status*", which essentially means "*Disabled*", as the camera was never turned on before. I assign a shortcut key **[Fn] + [F4]** to turn on/off the camera. And now the camera switches on and off, and even works.

I apologize for making this stupid question.